# WP7 AutoCompleteBox going crazy

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Good morning all,

I’m wondering, since the last WP7 sdk update there’s a *new* AutoCompleteBox included in the ns: Microsoft.Phone.Controls. I was basically using System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox, and I saw the new one so I told myself “Hey! A Phone oriented AutoCompleteBox ! Let’s replace the oldy one”. The thing is that, it is buggy… Actually It doesn’t seem to work at all, when you click on it, type a letter you get autocompletion, you choose a value the Text property gets filled with it alright *BUT* the keyboard never goes off (either after taping elsewhere or switching the screen)…. It has another big flaw… The TextChanged event is never triggered… So either there’s something wrong in the update, or the emulator is going nut.

Did somebody run into this already?
If not, any suggestions anyway?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers

Miloud B.

Answer (score 1):

The [November Update to the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) was the first time an "official" AutoCompleteBox has been made avaialble for the phone.

The sample on CodePlex works fine for me.

Can you confirm exactly which versions you are using.
Also, how and why are you wiring up the TextChanged event handler?

This is how I did it:

xaml:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{StaticResource words}" Margin="0,12" TextChanged="AutoCompleteBox_TextChanged" />
```

Code:

```
    private void AutoCompleteBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // arbitrary use of MessageBox just to confirm getting value entered
        MessageBox.Show(((AutoCompleteBox)(sender)).Text);
    }
```

Comment: I confirm having the exact same version (cf. Base version + November Update). It's weird that it works for you but I'm pretty sure I'm not doing things wrong since I've just dropped the AutoCompleteBox into my screen then I launchad the app on the emulator and tested it but it goes nut with the keyboard. Besides, I need the TextChanged Event because my app queries a remote service in order to get some data according to the input, this was working fine with the windows autocompletebox, with the new one, it doesn't fire the event at all.